# What are the plans for careers.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

So I see that careers.stackoverflow.com is a huge asset of stackoverflow but I also see there is exactly 0 hits if I search for jobs in Chile and I guess it might be similar for other regions of the world.

$350 per month is quite a price tag but it's absolutely justified in the US. Are there any plans to make this price depend on the region of the company?

Secondly to cover all the world, payment might be an issue. Are there any plans to accept Bitcoins for payment?

Comment: Huh? It is $350 if you are looking for candidates. To become a candidate, you need an invite (which will be free).

Comment: Right, 350$ might be a reason nobody around is looking for a candidate, so I ask to make this depend on the region and to tackle all other hard entry barriers if they exist, like payment limitations of a paypal not operating for half the world's countries.

Comment: We don't accept Paypal anymore. We take credit cards and wire transfers(depending on the circumstance). So theoretically we can take payment from anywhere in the world because either your bank or credit card company should convert the currency. We also also accept payment in local currencies in the specific markets we support.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have been slowly launching (and localizing) into other markets, starting with the [UK](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/uk), [Germany](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/de) and [France](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/fr). When we do, we take the local currency and set a price for the market that is more in line with the country.

I don't think we have any specific plans for Chile, however. And there are no plans for accepting Bitcoin.

Comment: Ok, so although I don't like the answer at all, I guess I have to accept it. 

Just allow me to nag one last time:
Bitcoin and English are all the localization most programmers' would need to have it work globally. Reasons to boycott me should not be technical in nature. Not on a programmers knowledge database like SO. Being cut out of such a great market just because I live in Chile really is … unfortunate.

Comment: @Giszmo Not everyone is as trusting of Bitcoin as you are.

Comment: You don't need to trust Ƀ in order to accept it. Use BitPay and you never touch ɃɃ but you can receive $$ from all over the world that the clients paid as ɃɃ. Guess what, not everyone is as trusting of USD as you are.